# Handling throttling Errors with Microsoft Graph SDK C# 5.2x

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, throttling

I'm using the Microsoft Graph SDK for C# to read data from Microsoft Graph. I also utilize the Microsoft Developer Proxy to simulate responses with an HTTP 429 status (TooManyRequests) for testing purposes.

However, upon encountering a 429 status, the SDK's default behavior is to retry the request up to three times. If it still gets a 429 response after the third retry, it throws a System.InvalidOperationException with the message "Too many retries performed." This behavior is evident from the proxy's output.

Here's the relevant code:

```cs
var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider(_token));
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

var myTeams = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .JoinedTeams
    .GetAsync(requestConfiguration => requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "Id" });
```

And the proxy's output:

```bash
 request     GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams?$select=Id
   chaos   ╭ 429 TooManyRequests
           ╰ GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/joinedTeams?$select=Id
...
```

My question is: How can I override the default behavior of the Microsoft Graph SDK for C# to handle the 429 status code myself? Ideally, I'd like to either adjust the request rate or implement other custom handling when this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either pass per-request options to the default http middleware

```
var retryHandlerOption = new RetryHandlerOption
{
    MaxRetry = 7,
    ShouldRetry = (delay,attempt,message) => true
};

var myTeams = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .JoinedTeams
    .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "Id" };
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Options.Add(retryHandlerOption);
    });
```

Or replace the default [RetryHandler](https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-http-dotnet/blob/main/src/Middleware/RetryHandler.cs) with custom implementation

```
public class CustomRetryHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Creating `GraphServiceClient` with replaced default `RetryHandler`

```
var authenticationProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider(_token));
var handlers = GraphClientFactory.CreateDefaultHandlers();
// dummy replacement
var retryHandler = handlers.FirstOrDefault(x => x is RetryHandler);
var index = handlers.IndexOf(retryHandler);
handlers[index] = new CustomRetryHandler();
var httpClient = GraphClientFactory.Create(handlers);

var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(httpClient, authenticationProvider);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Replacing the default RetryHandler does exactly what I need!

Comment: What is it exactly that you put in inside the CustomRetryHandler's SendAsync?

Comment: Hi @JussiPalo, maybe it's a question for MaikeruK how he adjusted the rate, etc.